# include .phtml zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, helper

I have to add a feature to a quite big app using zend framework.

i have a view. in that view, i have a if and want to include an other .phtml on the same location.

so, at the moment i got something like

```
if (x = true)
    require_once(the other file);
```

that works, but isnt in the meaning of zend. i've been told i should use view helpers, more specific, the partial. so, how do i include a phtml file with the partial? i dont get it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `render()` view helper like this:

```
<?=$this->render('the other.phtml')?>
```

All view variables available in the current .phtml script will be available in `the other.phtml` too.

If you want to render the other view script with specific view variables, use `partial` instead:

```
<?=$this->partial('the other.phtml', array(
    'var'=>'value',
    'var2'=>'value2',
    ...
))?>
```

Comment: Look [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) for docs. The array is the view variables to set inside of `the other.phtml`. Use `xxx/myscript.phtml` as path (including `xxx/`).